# Why is \n not working with input() command?

Tags: python, file, input

I'm working on a little side project and I have a small issue currently. The user enters their name through a `input`, and then it is saved to a text file. Everything works fine but when it comes to making a new line with `\n` to separate the names, it replaces the previous text in the text file. I can't seem to find the reason why online. Any help would be appreciated!

```
name = input("Name: "))

with open("names.txt", "w") as w:
    w.write(name + "\n")
```

Comment: "w" mode erases the current file. Did you want "a" mode to append new lines?

Comment: Didn't know "w" erases before writing. Changed it to "a" and now it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use "a+" to append if it exists and create a new file otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong flag, `w` means writing over any existing content, the solution is to use `a` for appending new content,

`with open("names.txt", "a") as w:`

reference: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)